# Issues while reading value of input field in popover using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a part of HTML like this which is generated dynamically. all tha value in popover are also generated dynamically. for now I have shown only one `<li>` value with the `id = "loc"` which is also given dynamically. I want to read the value of input field with `id = "loc"`. whatever I have tried i can mention below:

in the first line of html you can see `id = "close"` . When a user will click on a icon with `id = "close"` I need to reed the value of li in the popover with the `id = "loc"`.

I have tried

```
$('#data').on('click','.icon-remove',function(){

//var ptr=$(this).parents("tr.task");

//console.log($('i#close').find('p').css('background-color', 'red'));
//console.log(ptr.find(("#loc").val()));
//console.log($("#loc").val());
var $pel = $('.popover').find('#details')
console.log($pel.find('li#loc').val()); // through this I'm getting undefined
console.log($('.popover').find('#loc').val()); // this is giving me undefined

$('.popover').remove();

});

<i id=" close" class="icon-remove title-inner-pop closePop"></i>
<div class="popover-content">
<div>
<div class="more-option">


<span class="labels">1Yr Analytics</span>
<p>12 calls 15hours</p>
<a hrf="#">More...</a>
</div>
<div id="details">
<li>
<span class="labels">Location -</span>
<p>
<input id="loc" type="text" value="d">
</p>
</li>
```

I'll be really happy If some one can suggest me something to read the value in the input field with `id = "loc"` when someone click on icon inside popover with `id="close"`.
thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be nice if you'd format your html. Now it's very hard to read.

Comment: `.find(id)` should *never* occur. ID's should be unique, and you should only use `$('#id')` to get them.

Comment: Your HTML markup is quite messy and isn't semantically correct...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your over complicating this way to much. You have id's on your elements there is ZERO reason to use the `find()`. `find()` is for using advanced queries for dynamic content.

You have very static content simply use the below and that should work.

```
$("#close").click(function(){
    var input = $("#loc").val();
})
```